# How to Conditionally Apply a Series of Operations?

Tags: scala

I have this logic that a data file needs to go through a series of operations, but whether or not an operation is needed is controlled by some boolean. Basically the data array goes through the process loop and yields some result.

I wonder if there is an elegant way to code this, hopefully not using `var`s and lots of `if`/`else` statements?

```
def op1(data): Seq[int]
def op2(data): Seq[int]
def op3(data): Seq[int]

def process(data: Seq[int], b1: boolean, b2: boolean, b3: boolean) = {

  //NOT working code, some thing does the following:  
  var temp: Seq[int] = data
  if (b1) 
    temp = op1(temp)
  if(b2)
    temp = op2(temp)
  if(b3)
    temp = op3(temp)

  temp
```

}

Comment: Can you have a list of functions and a list of booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I actually prefer your solution, but this is a more functional alternative. I replaced the Seq with Strings, because they are easier to use for examples, but that shouldn't matter.

```
object SequenceOfOperations {
    def op1(data: String) = data + "A"            //> op1: (data: String)java.lang.String
    def op2(data: String) = data + "B"            //> op2: (data: String)java.lang.String
    def op3(data: String) = data + "C"            //> op3: (data: String)java.lang.String

    def process(data: String, b1: Boolean, b2: Boolean, b3: Boolean) = {
        val ops =Seq((b1 , op1(_)),(b2 , op2(_)),(b3 , op3(_)))

        val filteredOps = ops.filter( _._1).map (_._2)

        filteredOps.foldLeft(data)((l : String,o : String => String) => o(l))
    }                                             //> process: (data: String, b1: Boolean, b2: Boolean, b3: Boolean)String


    process("Z", true, false, true)               //> res0: String = ZAC
    process("Y", true, true, false)               //> res1: String = YAB
    process("X", false, false, true)              //> res2: String = XC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical fold, which you could wrap in the following function:

```
def maybeDo[A](bs: List[Boolean], fs: List[A => A], x: A) =
  (bs zip fs).foldLeft(x) {
    case (x, (b, f)) => if (b) f(x) else x
  }
```

Use it for example as follows

```
> val bs = List(true, false, true)
> val fs: List[Int => Int] = List(_+1, _*3, _+2)
> maybeDo(bs, fs, 10)
res0: Int = 13
```

In your example it would be something like

```
val temp = maybeFold(List(b1, b2, b3), List(op1 _, op2 _, op3 _), data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this..

One possible way can be..

```
 def op1(data: Seq[Int]) = data.map(_ + 2) //your actual operation here..
 def op2(data: Seq[Int]) = data.map(_ - 2) //..returning Seq[Int]
 def op3(data: Seq[Int]) = data.map(_ * 2) //

 implicit class SeqOps(val data: Seq[Int]) extends AnyVal {
   def op(op: Seq[Int] => Seq[Int], b: Boolean) = if (b) op(data) else data
 }
```

And then `def process` can be written as..

```
def process(data: Seq[Int], b1: Boolean, b2: Boolean, b3: Boolean) = {
     data op (op1, b1) op (op2, b2) op (op3, b3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the process signature not to change...

```
// continuing from the ops psuedocode

def process(data: Seq[Int], b1:Boolean, b2:Boolean, b3:Boolean): Seq[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop (acc: Seq[Int], ops: List[Seq[Int] => Seq[Int]]): Seq[Int] = {
    ops match {
      case List () => acc
      case head :: tail => loop (head(acc), tail)
    }
  }
  loop (data, List(( b1,op1 _), (b2,op2 _),(b3,op3 _)).filter{ _._1 }.map{ _._2 })
}
```

The solution is to pair the op with the correct Boolean, in a List, filter out the pairs with untrue Booleans, map the filtered pairs to a list of ops (basically dropping the boolean part of each surviving pair), Then accumulate your transformations recursively over your input data.

Here's what it results with some simple operators:
    import scala.annotations.tailrec

```
def op1(s: Seq[Int]) = s map {_ + 1}
def op2(s: Seq[Int]) = s map {_ * 2}
def op3(s: Seq[Int]) = s map {_ - 5}

def process(data: Seq[Int], b1:Boolean, b2:Boolean, b3:Boolean): Seq[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop (acc: Seq[Int], ops: List[Seq[Int] => Seq[Int]]): Seq[Int] = {
    ops match {
      case List () => acc
      case head :: tail => loop (head(acc), tail)
    }
  }
  loop (data, List(( b1,op1 _), (b2,op2 _),(b3,op3 _)).filter{ _._1 }.map{ _._2 })
}

process(Seq(1,2,3), true, false, true) // Seq[Int] = List(-3, -2, -1)
process(Seq(1,2,3), true, false, false) // Seq[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
process(Seq(1,2,3), false, true, false) // Seq[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: phone entry sucks. lost all newlines in the code block. Meta: how to fix?

Comment: remove <code> tag from your markup select your code block and press CTRL + K or CMD + K if you r using mac, or just wrap your block with \`code\`